# Linq to Entity Framework: Select with only subset of child elements

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

The following setup is true:

> - A is parent class
> - A has one to many of B
> - A has one to many of C
> - B has one to many of X
> - C has one to many of X
> - X has a property called EndDate: this is the filter criteria

I want to retrieve a set that has A, B, C and X (A.B.X and A.C.X)
I want to filter the set to that only elements are returned that have `X.EndDate = Date`.

I **don't** want elements of X that don't pass this criteria.
Can this be done in a single Select?

I'm currently trying following code:

```
var set = _context.Set<A>()
    .Include("B.X")
    .Include("C.X")
    .Where(a => a.B.Any(b => b.X.Any(x => x.EndDate == date)) ||
                a.C.Any(c => c.X.Any(x => x.EndDate == date)))
    .ToList();
```

However, when `B.X` is within filter criteria, it will also include C.X
And when one of `B.X` (X can be many) is true to the criteria, it will return all of `B.X` entities

**I tried my best to give an example:**

```
A           B           X       X.EndDate
A1          B1          BX1     2015-01-01
A1          B1          BX2     2015-01-02
A1          B2          BX3     2015-01-09

A           C           X       X.EndDate
A1          C1          CX1     2015-01-03
A1          C1          CX2     2015-01-03
A1          C2          CX3     2015-01-02

When date == 2015-01-02

Results are:
A1 B1 BX1
      BX2
   B2 BX3
   C1 CX1
      CX2
   C2 CX3 

Desired results are:
A1 B1 BX2
   C2 CX2
```

**Note:** I can only use this notation and not the SQL-like notation.
There are more entities that need to be included and this can (apparently) only be done by .Include("") with quotes

Comment: Consider showing a sample input, output values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is filter the included tables and that is not something that Entity Framework supports right now: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/47.  If you are dealing with simple classes then you could instantiate new A's in your select statement like this:

```
var set = _context.Set<A>()
    .Include("B.X")
    .Include("C.X")
    .Where(a => a.B.Any(b => b.X.Any(x => x.EndDate == date)) ||
                a.C.Any(c => c.X.Any(x => x.EndDate == date)))
    .Select(a => new A() 
    {
        B = a.B
            .Where(b => b.X.Any(x => x.EndDate == DatePicker))
            .Select(b => new B()
                {
                    X = b.X.Where(x => x.EndDate == DatePicker) 
                }),
        C = a.C
            .Where(c => c.X.Any(x => x.EndDate == DatePicker))
            .Select(c => new C()
                {
                    X = c.X.Where(x => x.EndDate == DatePicker) 
                })
    });
```

If your classes are not so simple, i.e. you have many properties that you would have to map in your select statement or you have complex business validation rules, then your best bet may be to continue with the query you have and simply remove the B's, C's and X's you don't want from your resulting set before using it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Out of curiousity: when you use the first .Select, are the items detached from the context?
Secondly: before you can remove items, aren't you pulling to many data from the DB? I suspect that the remove statements are not party of the original query?

Comment: Actually, this solution may be entirely wrong, unfortunately.  I am conflating LINQ to objects and LINQ to Entities.  Further research suggests that Entity Framework will not allow you to project to a mapped entity.  So, in light of that, your first question is moot.

Comment: Regarding your second question, yes you would be pulling more data from the DB than you actually need.  However, that may not be the main issue.  Your first question seems to imply your intend on committing these objects back to the database at some point (I am assuming that is why you are concerned about them being detached from the context).  If that is the case then removing the unwanted B's, C's and X's is not going to work for you anyways because EF would pick those deletions up as changes to the entity and it would persist those changes to the DB.

Comment: If fact, if it is the case that you intend on committing the entity back to the DB, I am not entirely sure it is going to be possible for you to get back a partial entity like your example suggests that you want.

Comment: I'm not commiting these entities back into the DB. This is an overview resultset. I was just wondering about the technical details :)

Comment: If that is the case then you could still utilize what I have but instead of projecting to partial entities you would project to an anonymous type.  If you go the route of using `Include` then I think you are going to pull down extra data no matter what.  The first `Where` will at least eliminate any A's where B AND C do not meet the criteria.  It is when B OR C matches that you are going to start pulling down more data than you need.  Say B match but not C but the include will ensure that C still comes back in the query.

Comment: If you are concerned about pulling down more data than you need (and why wouldn't any sane person be concerned) then I think you have two options.  The first is to pull the A's, B's and C's down in separate queries and build your objects from the resulting sets. Where each query pulls only what you need and no more.  The second option is @Fyodor's solution.  He is flattening the object so you would have to rebuild your objects but that can be handled with a couple of `GroupBy` clauses.  His solution could still potentially bring back a lot of data if tables A, B or C are very wide.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I think pulling B and C seperately would serve me best :)

Comment: I'm voting this as the answer, since you already state that filtering subqueries can't be done in EF at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
from a in _context.Set<A>()
from b in a.B
from c in a.C

let bx = b.X.Where( x => x.EndDate == date )
let cx = c.X.Where( x => x.EndDate == date )

where bx.Any() || cx.Any()

select { a, b, c, bx, cx };
```

Note that you may get repeated `a`, `b`, and/or `c` in the result set.

**Update**
If you cannot use LINQ syntax, this trivially (though kinda ugly) translates to extension method calls:

```
_context.Set<A>()
.SelectMany( a => a.B, (a, b) => new { a, b, bx = b.X.Where( ... ) } )
.SelectMany( x => x.a.C, (x, c) => new { x.a, x.b, x.bx, c, cx = c.X.Where( ... ) } )
.Where( x => x.bx.Any() || x.cx.Any() )
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What if I can only use the .Select notation (as in my example) because there are other layers inbetween.
I can only use .include("") with quotes to allow all entities to be correctly mapped.

Comment: This LINQ notation trivially translates into `.Select` et al, see update.